# How can I use RecognizerIntent to force using Turkish?

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition, google-voice-search

to voice recognation:

I use this code to detect:

```
Intent myintent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        myintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        myintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, lcl );
```

the `lcl` is a variable. I choice **turkish** it works on turkish but at the same time works with **english**

I do not understand If google understand every language why we use **EXTRA_LANGUAGE** parameter.

> I want to google force to detect **turkish**

is it possible

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
        recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "tr-TR");
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
```

Comment: I give extra language **  myintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, lcl );**